# font-family vs font face

Tags: html, css, input

I have read a few other threads here and on other sites about this issue, but I haven't found any solution that actually works using only CSS. Here is my issue. I want all of the input fields that have text descriptors (such as checkboxes and radio buttons) to have the Arial font. If I do this:

```
  <INPUT type=radio name="Shaded" id="Flat" value="Flat"
    onclick="OnItemSelect('Shaded',2);"><FONT face="Arial" size=2>Flat</FONT>
```

the word Flat within the font tag shows up as Arial. But if I do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style  type="text/css">
  input {
  font-size:8pt;
  font-family:Arial!important;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <INPUT type=radio name="Shaded" id="Flat" value="Flat"
    onclick="OnItemSelect('Shaded',2);">Flat
</body>
</html>
```

the word Flat shows up Times New Roman (my default page font). I have tried using a class (.inp) and it still doesn't work. What can I do to get this word to show up as Arial without having to use the FONT tag?

**Edit:** I removed the offensive <BR> from this post, but left the line split over two lines to prevent horizontal scrolling. I want to thank everyone who responded, as your help made the difference. But now I have one further issue with this, but on a checkbox instead of a radio button. Here's the code:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" id="app" name="multiple_entry" value="multiple-type">
<STRONG><LABEL for="app"> Is </LABEL></STRONG>
<INPUT size=1 maxlength=1 value="0" name="current_entry">
<STRONG><LABEL for="app"> of </LABEL></STRONG>
<INPUT size=1 maxlength=1 value="0" name="max_entries">
<STRONG><LABEL for="app"> monsters of this kind.</LABEL></STRONG>
```

It works as expected when clicking on the text, but clicking the input boxes for the numbers doesn't affect the checkbox. Is there a way to make it where if the user clicks on one of those two inputs that it automatically checks the checkbox?

I don't know how to make use of the "try it" thing to be able to give you a way to see the button in action. Sorry.

Comment: you are targeting the input that has nothing to do with the text. Wrap the text inside span (or label) and target that element

Comment: '90 called, they want `<font>` back. `<font>` is deprecated. Also you do not select text via CSS, that's why it's not working. As @TemaniAfif told, wrap in in some element to target via CSS

Comment: There's something very wrong with the HTML code here; the `<BR>` tag is smack in the middle of the `<INPUT` tag, and that's just bad news.

Comment: That <BR> I added in this post to break the line without you thinking it was that way in my actual webpage. I abhor horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Haha Justinas. Very funny. I am trying to get away from using those tags, but sometimes CSS is not so cooperative.

Comment: That sounds like the answer, Temani Afif. I will go that route.

Comment: The Flat text is not part of the input tag. The <BR> should not be inside the input tag. That is invalid HTML. If you are having horizontal scroll issues then that can be solved in a number of different ways. If you want to globally assign Arial to all the text on the page, then do body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}.

Comment: I guess I should not have added the <BR> tag in this post. It never existed in the actual document. I put it here because I didn't want you guys to have to scroll horizontally to see the entire tag. I use TextPad for editing, and I use the wrap text mode so I don't have to scroll horizontally. Also, my entire purpose in this effort is to revamp old pages and bring them up-to-date with proper structure and code, and changing all FONT tags and element attributes (where applicable) to CSS. I am not yet using a separate .css file. I am putting all of the CSS into STYLE tags in the HEAD section.

Comment: I just wanted you guys to know the line was broken by me, on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone else has pointed out, you have several problems in your code, but here's a quick example of how you could do it. The first targets everything inside a `<label>` element (red) and the second is a bit more specific, targeting the word "flat" specifically with a css class (blue):

```css
label {
  font-family: arial;
  color: red;
}

.my-classname {
  font-family: arial;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type=radio name="Shaded" id="Flat" value="Flat" onclick="OnItemSelect('Shaded',2);">
  Flat
</label>

<label>
  <input type=radio name="Shaded" id="Flat" value="Flat" onclick="OnItemSelect('Shaded',2);">
  <span class="my-classname">Flat</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, ray. I will be using the span tag. It's an easier fix since all I have to do is change FONT to SPAN. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WayneCa use the label element. you can put a span inside a label if you like, but you should have a label. if you set the `for` attribute of the label to match the `id` attribute of the radio button, then you can click on the words and the button gets selected. without the label, you can only click on the radio button circle itself. there are also accessibility concerns with leaving out the label, such as vision-impaired users with screenreading software. see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) for lots more code examples.

Comment: I was unaware of this. I will definitely look into using a label. Thanks.